# Array of IDs returned by wp_query

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a plugin and plugin adds a filter. Filter needs to select some things from database depending on post id (custom table). Now the thing is, if in the loop with say 20 posts, it'd run 20 queries which is not exactly great. So I'd like to know, if it's possible to do something like this:

1. After wp_query is ran on say category page (but before the loop), get array of IDs returned by it
2. Run 1 query with array from step 1 to get needed data for all posts and store it in global variable.
3. In filter retrieve data from global variable rather than run query for each time filter is called.

I want to know if it's possible to do this on both front-end (pages like category archive etc, basically everywhere where in_the_loop() is true) and back end (post listing, page listing, cpt listing). I googled alas couldn't find anything. If someone knows if it's possible to achieve, please let me know.

Comment: not a bad idea, but you will lose the data on page refresh. Object caching (wp has the functions to save built in but you need to install it on your server and drop in a object cache file, google this) would be a better idea. Its a bit ram intensive though so another option is to set a transient (wp term) with all the posts and the data needed and serve that. Or cache the whole html page using a caching plugin = less resource instensive.

Comment: Losing data on page refresh is fine with me. As long as I can reduce it from N queries to one query, that's already good enough for me. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: once the data has run once it is, also it depends on the funcitons you are using, if theres no caching, get post meta will hold the value (in a varible) so any of the same requests dont take another db query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I glanced through core code and found that `the_posts` seems to be the filter I'm looking for. It holds all of the post objects returned by the query and is accessible before posts are looped through.

Accessible like so:

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'testtest', '20', 1);

function testtest($posts)
{
    //do some magic here
    return $posts;
}
```

`$posts` is an array of WP_Post_Objects, which have the following keys:

```
[ID]
[post_author]
[post_date]
[post_date_gmt]
[post_content]
[post_title]
[post_excerpt]
[post_status]
[comment_status]
[ping_status]
[post_password]
[post_name]
[to_ping]
[pinged]
[post_modified]
[post_modified_gmt]
[post_content_filtered]
[post_parent]
[guid]
[menu_order]
[post_type]
[post_mime_type]
[comment_count]
[filter]
```

Hope this helps someone.